# Movement multiple objects in canvas to x,y coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics

I'm trying to use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eko24ive/4e4nD/1/) "moveTo(x,y)" (by [markE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411591/marke)) function for multiple objects.
[This](http://jsfiddle.net/eko24ive/sLU8A/3/) is what i've tried.
And this is what I'm tried to do:

Calculating and moving object in woriking example look like this:

```
pct += .01;
// if we're not done, request another animation frame
if (pct < 1.00) {
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
}

// Calculate the next XY position
var nextX = startingX + dx * pct;
var nextY = startingY + dy * pct;

// Draw the shape
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.fillRect(nextX, nextY, 40, 30);
```

And this, what I'm trying to do for multiple shapes:

```
var shapesLength = shapes.length;
for (var i = 0; i < shapesLength; i++) {// Loop through every object

var tmpShape = shapes[i];//selecting shape

    tmpShape.pct += .01;// increment pct towards 100%

    // if we're not done, request another animation frame
    if (tmpShape.pct < 1.00) {
        requestAnimFrame(animate);
    }

    // Calculate the next XY position
    var nextX = tmpShape.startingX + tmpShape.dx * tmpShape.pct;
        var nextY = tmpShape.startingY + tmpShape.dy * tmpShape.pct;

    // Draw the shape
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(nextX, nextY, 10, 10);
};
```

But something goes wrong, and I'm don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going wrong is that requestAnimFrame is inside your loop.

You'll want to call requestAnimFrame once outside your loop.

Here is example code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/HAbfm/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
          function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
        })();

        var shapes=[];
        shapes.push({startX:10,  startY:10,  endX:140, endY:140, color:"red"});
        shapes.push({startX:280, startY:10,  endX:150, endY:140, color:"green"});
        shapes.push({startX:10,  startY:280, endX:140, endY:150, color:"blue"});
        shapes.push({startX:280, startY:280, endX:150, endY:150, color:"gold"});

        var pct=0.00;
        var fps = 60;

        animate();

        function animate() {
            setTimeout(function() {


                // increment the percent (from 0.00 to 1.00)
                pct+=.01;

                // clear the canvas
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

                // draw all shapes
                for(var i=0;i<shapes.length;i++){

                    // get reference to next shape
                    var shape=shapes[i];

                    // note: dx/dy are fixed values
                    // they could be put in the shape object for efficiency
                    var dx=shape.endX-shape.startX;
                    var dy=shape.endY-shape.startY;
                    var nextX = shape.startX + dx * pct;
                    var nextY = shape.startY + dy * pct;                
                    var shape=shapes[i];
                    ctx.fillStyle=shape.color;
                    ctx.fillRect(nextX,nextY,7,7);
                }

                if(pct<1.00){requestAnimFrame(animate)};


            }, 1000 / fps);
        }


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=350></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an example of how to implement multiple waypoints for each shape:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/UNjdC/

**[ Addition: explain how to create shapes and animate them ]**

You create and animate shapes in 3 steps:

1. Create a polyline for one shape to follow during the animation.
2. Push a new shape into the shapes[] array.  Each shape object defines its own width, height, color and animation polyline from #1 above.
3. After all new shapes are in the shapes[] array, call animate() to animate all shapes along their own polypaths.

Here are the code bits for steps 1-3 above:

```
// 1. create a polyline for one shape to follow

points = pointsToSingleArray([
    {x:48,y:2},
    {x:48,y:365}
]);


// 2. push the shape into the shapes array
// 
// a shape object contains width/height/color and the polyline

shapes.push({
    width: shapeWidth,
    height: shapeHeight,
    waypoints: points,
    color: "red"
});

// 3. After you've pushed all desired shapes into the 
//    shapes[] array, call animate() to start draw all
//    objects along their own polyline paths.

animate();
```

Comment: Here's an example of how to implement multiple waypoints for each shape: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/UNjdC/

Comment: How create instant generation of objects and earse them after reaching destination point ?

Comment: The shapes[] array holds the definition of all shapes which will be drawn and animated.  In this case the shapes are all rectangles which have start/end animation points and colors.  If you want instant generation of objects, just add new objects to the shapes[] array.  If you want the object to disappear after reaching destination point, remove this line:      drawShape(shape, shape.waypoints.length - 1);

Comment: `function go() { points = pointsToSingleArray([{x: 48,y: 2}, {x: 48,y: 485}]);
shapes.push({width: shapeWidth,height: shapeHeight,waypoints: points,color: "red"}); }
setTimeout(go, 3000);`
Why this one don't work ?

Comment: Not enough code to debug...Your go() function sets some values but does not request any animations--Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I mean, that i can't generate shapes.

Comment: *You are generating a shape:* Red with dimensions of shapeWidth x shapeHeight.  After you define a shape(s), you must call animate() to draw and animate them: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/waXQm/

Comment: I don't get where i should define new generated shapes.
And i'm also don't get how generate shapes at all )

Comment: I've added to my answer and described the 3 step process for defining new shapes and animating them along their individual polylines.  Cheers!

Comment: Excuse me, but i don't see where i should write function/action of shape generation.
I'm tried to create function that generate shape:
`function gen_shape()
 {
 points = pointsToSingleArray([{x: 63,y: 486}, {x: 63,y: 2}]);
 shapes.push({width: 10,height: 10,waypoints: points,color: "red"
 });
 }`
And I'm call `gen_shape()` inside function `animate()`, but this is don't work.

Comment: **I see now…add shapes even while the animation is running.**  To add a shape while the animation is executing, you need each shape object to know how many steps it has completed through the waypoints array—so give each object a currentWaypoint property.   Add a new shape object like this: shapes.push({width:10, height:10, waypoints:points, color:"red", currentWaypoint:0}). During every  animation loop (1) draw each shape object at its own waypoints[currentWaypoint] and then (2) increment its currentWaypoint.  Stop animating a shape when its currentWaypoint>=waypoints.length.

Comment: You wasted all that detection logic trying to figure out if the browser supported requestAnimationFrame? and then you ignore it and setInterval, for a stuttering experience :)